# Lubridate Uexpected Result

Tags: r

I've encountered an unexpected result with the `lubridate` package. Here is a short example to calculate the physical passage of time using the function `time_length`; first directly, and then on an interval. It appears that the methods are identical using the "seconds" units, but are different using the "months" units. Does anyone know why this is the case?

For reference, I'm using:

```
R version: 3.5.1
lubridate version: 1.7.4
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
## generate two dates to illustrate issue
startDate <- ymd("2015-02-27")
endDate <- ymd("2015-03-02")

## calculate physical passage of time, in seconds
time_length(endDate - startDate, "seconds") # result: 259200
time_length(interval(startDate, endDate), "seconds") # result: 259200
# The methods above match, but...

## calculate physical passage of time, in months
time_length(endDate - startDate, "months") # result: 0.09863014
time_length(interval(startDate, endDate), "months") # result: 0.1071429
# The results no longer match! Why?
```

Comment: Months do not have a constant length

Comment: @Henry why would time_length(... and time_length(interval(... handle the length of months differently? If they do, how do they handle the length of months differently?

Comment: Because the difference between two dates is a period of time losing the anchor of the actual dates but an interval jeeps the start and end date knowing in particular which moths they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months do not have a constant length. You are trying to translate 259200 seconds, i.e. 3 days, into months

```
> endDate - startDate
Time difference of 3 days
```

Your  `0.09863014` is 3/(365/12) as an attempt to translate 3 arbitrary days into arbitrary months

```
> interval(startDate, endDate)
[1] 2015-02-27 UTC--2015-03-02 UTC
```

Your `0.1071429` is 3/28 as an attempt to translate 3 days starting in a non-leap-year February into months

Comment: Thanks for the additional context in your complete answer! Exactly the explanation we needed. Interval uses the count of days in the start date's month.